# prolog - not incrementing properly

Tags: prolog

I am trying to increment the variables U,D,L,R in the following program. However they don't seem to be incrementing at all.

```
maze(4,0,3,0,0).
cell(0,0,[d],[0.391538986557049]).
cell(1,0,[r,d],[16.597130417636, 0.889878639213553]).
cell(2,0,[l,d],[0.011123208182191, 18.6496954092342]).
cell(3,0,[],[]).
cell(0,1,[u,r],[63.1258159853081, 3.14882640637611]).
cell(1,1,[u,l,r,d],[0.577082416767899, 11.2788559044107, 0.0116108917113176, 25.6907194043197]).
cell(2,1,[u,l,r,d],[89.8399554017928, 0.120311605902415, 0.0687987167581341, 198.151088713489]).
cell(3,1,[l,d],[0.0114526228490019, 152.662532290366]).
cell(0,2,[r,d],[0.0148854629087619, 0.019301544005463]).
cell(1,2,[u,l,r],[9.93466159987408, 0.199913563972552, 1.26393492879008]).
cell(2,2,[u,l,d],[12.3336316807166, 1.59269860596813, 0.680879328533728]).
cell(3,2,[u],[18.8277117544323]).
cell(0,3,[u],[15.6415340291405]).
cell(1,3,[],[]).
cell(2,3,[u,r],[0.216152697975287, 0.0138637250041849]).
cell(3,3,[l],[0.0113867473179591]).

genXY(N,R) :- R = [X,Y], succ(N1, N), between(0, N1, X), between(0, N1, Y).

isMem(U, Dir, C, R) :- not(member(U,Dir)), R is C + 0.
isMem(U, Dir, C, R) :- member(U,Dir), R is C + 1.

stats(U,D,L,R) :-
    U is 0, D is 0, L is 0, R is 0,
    maze(Len,_,_,_,_),
    genXY(Len,Out), 
    [H,T|_] = Out,
    cell(H,T,Dir,_),
    isMem(u, Dir, U, U1), %from here
    U is U1,
    isMem(d, Dir, D, D1),
    D is D1,
    isMem(l, Dir, L, L1),
    L is L1,
    isMem(r, Dir, R, R1),
    R is R1.              %to here
```

IsMem function checks whether an element is in the list, If so, it increments the variable. If not, it returns the same value. As far as I know, the correct value is being returned from isMem but the variables U,L,D,R don't seem to be updating.

EDIT:

Expected output:

```
?- stats(U,D,L,R).
U = D, D = 8,
L = R, R = 7.
```

To clarify, The program looks at the first cell. The Dir for the first cell is [d]. So the variable D should be incremented by 1 and others should be left alone. The next cell has Dir [r,d]. So both R and D should be incremented. Now R should hold value 1 while D should hold 2. So essentially it counts how many u,l,d,r there are in a  given set of cells.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you means with updating... Prolog, like every declarative language, can only assign a value to a variable *once*. You cannot overwrite it.

Comment: @CommuSoft I see. So how would I increment U,L,D,R in this case?

Comment: once assigned you can't change a variable's content.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog and by extent *logic programming* and *declarative programming* work with variables in a different way that *imperative programming languages*: a variable can only be set **once**. In the case of logic programming, it is possible that some parts are still variable. But once you say `X=a`, you cannot reset it to `X=b` (unless if you have *backtracked*, or use the *non-backtrackable store* some Prolog systems offer).

So in case you have set:

```
U is 0, D is 0, L is 0, R is 0,
```

It means that `U`, `D`, `L` and `R` are set forever to zero.

However I don't see why you wish to overwrite the values at all, you can simply use zero and return the required value with:

```
stats(U,D,L,R) :-
    maze(Len,_,_,_,_),
    genXY(Len,Out), 
    [H,T|_] = Out,
    cell(H,T,Dir,_),
    isMem(u, Dir, 0, U),
    isMem(d, Dir, 0, D),
    isMem(l, Dir, 0, L),
    isMem(r, Dir, 0, R).
```

In other words call the predicate with `0` directly and use `U`, etc. to catch the result and return it.

Furthermore you can optimize your `isMem` a bit with:

```
isMem(U,Dir,C,R) :-
    member(U,Dir),
    !,
    R is C + 1.
isMem(_,_,C,C).
```

This will boost performance and is in many cases a safer way to specify a program since the last clause makes the predicate syntactically total.

**EDIT**

Based on what you wish to calculate in your answer, you might consider redesigning your program as. First write a program that increments the coordinate based on the size of the maze.

```
coorinc(X,Y,X1,Y) :-
    X1 is X+1,
    maze(N,_,_,_,_),
    X1 < N,
    !.
coorinc(_,Y,0,Y1) :-
    Y1 is Y+1,
    maze(N,_,_,_,_),
    Y1 < N.
```

Now you can use an *accumulator* to calculate the statistics:

```
stat(U,D,L,R) :-
    stats(0,0,0,0,0,0,U,D,L,R).
```

And now one needs to implement the logic for `stat/10`:

```
stats(X,Y,U0,D0,L0,R0,U,D,L,R) :-
    coorinc(X,Y,X1,Y1),
    !,
    cell(X,Y,Dir,_),
    isMem(u,Dir,U0,U1),
    isMem(d,Dir,D0,D1),
    isMem(l,Dir,L0,L1),
    isMem(r,Dir,R0,R1),
    stats(X1,Y1,U1,D1,L1,R1,U,D,L,R).

stats(X,Y,U0,D0,L0,R0,U,D,L,R) :-
    cell(X,Y,Dir,_),
    isMem(u,Dir,U0,U),
    isMem(d,Dir,D0,D),
    isMem(l,Dir,L0,L),
    isMem(r,Dir,R0,R).
```

Comment: That makes more sense. However I lose all previous values. The thing is I iterate through a number of cells and those set of isMem statments in the stats function are being run N times. (where N is the number of cells). I updated the original post with more cells.

Comment: @rightDrop: it is unclear what you want to achieve, please provide the output you aim to generate...

Comment: I added expected output and further clarification.

Comment: I should also mention that the expected output is just an example. I didn't actually count how many u,l,d,r there are in that set of cells.

Comment: @rightDrop: what is the use of `Out`? You don't seem to do anything with that variable at all...

Comment: I extract H and T from Out. And I use it to access each cell.